# open a new view inside app delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

the app delegate.h file is as follows

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AFAViewController;
@class OpenInChromeController;
@class AFABarcodeScanner;


@interface AFAAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
{

    OpenInChromeController *openInChromeController_;
    AFABarcodeScanner *bs;

}



@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic)AFAViewController *viewController;

@property(strong,nonatomic)AFABarcodeScanner *bs;



@end
```

the app delegate.m file is as follows

```
#import "AFAAppDelegate.h"
#import "AFAViewController.h"
#import "OpenInChromeController.h"
#import "AFABarcodeScanner.h"


@implementation AFAAppDelegate

@synthesize bs;


@synthesize window;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        self.viewController = [[AFAViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AFAViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }

    else
    {
        self.viewController = [[AFAViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AFAViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}




- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                    @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chrome/id535886823"]];

    }
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

    UIAlertView *alertView;
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"inside open url" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    AFABarcodeScanner *vc = [[AFABarcodeScanner alloc] initWithNibName:@"AFABarcodeScanner" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];



    return YES;
}




@end
```

i would like open the new view inside the custom url function. When the request is obtained from external web page the view inside the application delegate must be opened.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to achieve it:

First: AppDelegate has a property window. A window is a view, so you can do

```
[self.window addSubview:newView];
```

Second: a view controller can reach the window without dealing with the app delegate.

```
[controller.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Could you please explain me the code.

Comment: if you're using the First option, add this after the `addSubview`: `[self.window bringSubviewToFront:newView];`

Comment: @user2541457 did you succeed in what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Get the instance of the AFAViewController(self.viewController) and add the subview to this view or else present AFABarcodeScanner as model if possible